# How to add text above the navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

how to add assistant text above navigation bar or toolbar. Just like this in the mail app, i want a big navigation bar with some text above titles.

Should I use navigation bar or use a toolbar and how should I implement that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is property named "**prompt**" in **UINavigationBarItem**. Refer [**UINavigationBarItem Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-SW12)

That one will solved exactly your requirement. This property will allow developer to add a title above the navigation bar. You can simply try with doing the same in sample storyboard example.

Check this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That is `UINavigationItem`'s `prompt`.

Like this:

```
[[self navigationItem] setPrompt:@"YourString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prompt` property of `UINavigationItem`.

`self.navigationItem.prompt = @"Extra text;`

See doc for reference:

[Reference for Prompt Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/prompt)